# What is the difference between /auth and /authenticate?

Tags: c#, authorization, servicestack

Swagger exposes the following endpoints :

[image: swagger]

The payloads look identicle and the documentation : 
https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization

Never mentions the /authenticate endpoint. The DTO generator for typescript also shows these as being identicle.

Is there a difference ?  Is there a different use case for both ?  Is it merely a legacy endpoint?

Is there a way to hide /authenticate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both [aliases to the ServiceStack's `AuthenticateService`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/6d6ba251b3201cd5fcea37738f25f1f6bd05ca68/src/ServiceStack/AuthFeature.cs#L139-L142), preserved for backwards compatibility.

You can remove the previous `/authenticate` routes after registering the `AuthFeature` plugin with:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...));

GetPlugin<AuthFeature>().ServiceRoutes[typeof(AuthenticateService)] = new[] {
    "/auth", "/auth/{provider}"
};
```